# Check if $||.||_{1}$ and $||.||_{\infty}$ are strictly convex norms on $\mathbb{C}^n$ for $n \geq 2$.

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

A norm is strictly convex on a given normed space $X$ if, for every $x,y \text{ with } x \neq y \in X$ of norm 1, we have that $||x + y|| < 2$.

$||.||_{1} = \sum_{j}^{n}|x_j|$

Say we take the set $N = \{x \in \mathbb{C}^{n} s.t. ||x||=1 \text{ and } n \geq 2\}$ and take $x,y \in N$

So $||x||_1 = \sum_{j}^{n}|a_j + b_ji| = \sum_{j}^{n}[(a_j)^2 + (b_j)^2]^{1/2} = 1$.

And we would have $||x + y||= \sum_{j}^{n}|(a_j + b_ji) + (a’_j + b’_ji)|$.

After performing the sum, we’d end up with 
$||x + y||= \sum_{j}^{n}|(a_j + a’_j) +(b_ji + b’ _ji)|$

And then taking the modulus: $||x + y|| = \sum_{j}^{n}[(a’’_j)^2 +(b’’_j)^2]^{1/2}$

Can we show that this sum is strictly less than 2?

---

As for the second part
$||.||_{\infty} = \sup_{j}|x_j|$ for $j=1,2,...,n$

And the sum would be $||x+y||= sup_j|x_j + y_j| = sup_j[(a’’j)^2 + (b’’j)^2]^{1/2}$

Then again, how is this actually less than 2.

Comment: You definitely have $||x+y||\le2$ by the triangle inequality, so you just need to rule out equality. When does equality in the triangle inequality hold?

Comment: @Thorgott, indeed, I did actually check that the inequality holds. But I’m still struggling to see how $\sum_{j}^{n}[(a’’j)^2 + (b’’j)^2]^{1/2}$ fails to be equal to 2.

Comment: This is why asked when equality in the triangle inequality holds. You can see that equality in the triangle inequality of the $1-$ and $\infty-$norm hold iff equality holds in the usual absolute value triangle inequality for complex numbers. When does that hold and why can this scenario be ruled out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, strictly convex means that for $x,y\in X$ *with* $x\neq y$ such that $\|x\|=\|y\|=1$, we have $\|x+y\|<2$.

Secondly, this does not hold for $\mathbb C^n$ with $n\geq 2$ and the $1$-norm.  Indeed, consider $n=2$, $x=(1,0)$, $y=(0,1)$.  Then $\|x\|_1=\|y\|_1=1$, while $\|x+y\|_1=2$.

Thirdily, this does not hold for $\mathbb C^n$ with $n\geq 2$ and the $\infty$-norm.  Again, consider $n=2$, but with $x=(1,0)$ and $y=(1,1)$.  Then $\|x\|_\infty=\|y\|_\infty=1$, while $\|x+y\|_\infty=2$.

Comment: @Aweygian, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome.  Glad to help!